# ActiveRecord: How to sort a collection of models via an attribute containing letters and numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I'm trying to sort a collection of objects in Rails, and because the Name values contain letters and numbers, `Model.all.order(:name)` doesn't work as desired (eg, *apple10* comes before *apple9*).

The example code at http://www.bofh.org.uk/2007/12/16/comprehensible-sorting-in-ruby solves my problem if I input an array:

```
["apple10","banana20","banana3","apple9"].sort_by { |key| key.split(/(\d+)/).map { |v| v =~ /\d/ ? v.to_i : v } }

=> ["apple9", "apple10", "banana3", "banana20"]
```

How can I apply that code (or something similar) in ActiveRecord, eg:

```
Model.all.sensible_sort(:name)
```

I tried using the code from [the above URL](http://www.bofh.org.uk/2007/12/16/comprehensible-sorting-in-ruby) in a helper, in the controller, and in the model definition, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Model.all.sort_by { |instance| instance.name.split(/(\d+)/).map { |v| v =~ /\d/ ? v.to_i : v } }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with how to get the reference to the object inside the sort_by - this is great to know